# How to overlay circle and semi-circle elements using css-grid for resposive design

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm new to css and I have a specific question about overlaying using *css grid*.

What I am trying to achieve is having 5 circles overlaying each other. These five circles comprise two boxes on each side of a fifth circle made out of two semi-circles. I want each circle(Or semicircle) to be a different colour/object.

I want it to be responsive, so I have used a grid system.
This has caused less problems then when I attempted to resolve the problem using  flex, but it still doesn't work as I need.

Here is the image of what I want to create:
[image: Circles]

Currently, the circles in the left box work perfectly, but in the right box the first element (black semi-circle) doesn't start in the left side of the box and I don't know why.

I had to use the margin property to "stick" it to the left side of the box. But then it doesn't work as responsively as I want and as it works in the left box.

Can anyone tell me please where is the problem?

Thank you

**EDIT**

I should have been clearer.
All elements in the right (white) box aren't working properly. Beside the problem with black semi-circle, the green circles are overflowing the parent div, when screen size is smaller.

I'm trying to figure out, why these elements don't behave same as the elements in the left box. And how to fix it.

Here is the code (without using the margin property):

```css
html {
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
}

:root {
  --yellowgreen: #ECF22E;
  --applegreen: #BCDD15;
  --brightgreen: #f4ff96;
}

/*||Circles -----------------------------*/
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.circle {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.circle p {
  margin: 0;
}

.circle span {
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.semi-circle {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.semi-circle p {
  margin: 0;
}

.semi-circle span {
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: normal;
}

#dark-box {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: repeat(4, 1fr) / repeat(5, 1fr);
  width: 40rem;
  border-top: 2px solid var(--applegreen);
  border-bottom: 2px solid var(--applegreen);
  background-color: black;
}

#bright-box {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: repeat(4, 1fr) / repeat(5, 1fr);
  width: 40rem;
  border-top: 2px solid var(--applegreen);
  border-bottom: 2px solid var(--applegreen);
  background-color: white;
}

.section-introduction .circle {
  text-align: center;
  height: 16rem;
  width: 16rem;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.brightgreen-circle {
  grid-row: 2 / span 2;
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
  background-color: var(--brightgreen);
}

.yellowgreen-circle {
  grid-row: 2 / span 2;
  grid-column: 3 / span 2;
  background-color: var(--yellowgreen);
}

.left-semi-circle {
  border-radius: 16rem 0 0 16rem;
  height: 16rem;
  width: 8rem;
  grid-row: 2 / span 2;
  grid-column: 5 / span 1;
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
}

.right-semi-circle {
  border-radius: 0 16rem 16rem 0;
  height: 16rem;
  width: 8rem;
  color: white;
  grid-row: 2 / 4;
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: black;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
}

.applegreen-circle {
  grid-row: 2 / 4;
  grid-column: 2 / span 2;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: var(--applegreen);
}

.brightgreen-circle2 {
  grid-row: 2 / 4;
  grid-column: 4 / span 2;
  background-color: var(--brightgreen);
}
```

```html
<section class="section-introduction">
  <h2 class="section-heading">Color pallete</h2>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="dark-box">
      <div class="brightgreen-circle circle ">
        <p>brightgreen</p>
        <span>#F4FF96</span>
      </div>
      <div class="yellowgreen-circle circle">
        <p>yellowgreen</p>
        <span>#ECF22E</span>
      </div>
      <div class="left-semi-circle semi-circle">
        <p>White</p>
        <span>#FFFFFF</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="bright-box">
      <div class="right-semi-circle semi-circle">
        <p>Black</p>
        <span>#000000</span>
        
        </p>
        
      </div>
      <div class="applegreen-circle circle">
        <p>applegreen</p>
        <span>#BCDD15</span>
      </div>
      <div class="brightgreen-circle2 circle">
        <p>brightgreen</p>
        <span>#F4FF96</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: In the snippet it looks like the black semicircle is touching the left line. What browser/OS are you using? I can't reproduce your issue.

Comment: It's because I used the margin property as I wrote. I edited the code and my question to be more clear. It is also touching the left line when the screen size is smaller, but it is not the only problem.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a gradient for the background and a single container where you can set within your circle.

If you use 4 columns for each circle, the forth can be used for the overlapping. If that is too much, try use 5 or 6 columns.

here is the example of the idea:

```css
html {
  font-family: "Titillium Web", sans-serif;
  font-size: clamp(10px, 1.5vw, 30px);
}

:root {
  --yellowgreen: #ecf22e;
  --applegreen: #bcdd15;
  --brightgreen: #f4ff96;
}
/*||Circles -----------------------------*/

.container {
  display:grid;
  align-items:center;
  height:30rem;
  width:max-content;
  margin:auto;
  background:linear-gradient(to right,black 50%, white 50%);
  border-top: 2px solid var(--applegreen);
  border-bottom: 2px solid var(--applegreen);
}

.brightgreen-circle {
  grid-row:1;
  grid-column: 1 / span 4;
}

.yellowgreen-circle {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 4 / span 4;
}

.left-semi-circle {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 7 / span 2;
}

.right-semi-circle {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 9 / span 2;
  z-index: 10;
}

.applegreen-circle {
  grid-row:1;
  grid-column: 10 / span 4;
}

.brightgreen-circle2 {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 13 / span 4;
}

.circle {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.circle p {
  margin: 0;
}

.circle span {
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.semi-circle {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.semi-circle p {
  margin: 0;
}

.semi-circle span {
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: normal;
}





.section-introduction .circle {
  text-align: center;
  height: 16rem;
  width: 16rem;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}


.brightgreen-circle {
  background-color: var(--brightgreen);
}

.yellowgreen-circle {
  background-color: var(--yellowgreen);
}

.left-semi-circle {
  border-radius: 16rem 0 0 16rem;
  height: 16rem;
  width: 8rem;
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
}

.right-semi-circle {
  border-radius: 0 16rem 16rem 0;
  height: 16rem;
  width: 8rem;
  color: white;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: black;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
}

.applegreen-circle {
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: var(--applegreen);
}

.brightgreen-circle2 {
  background-color: var(--brightgreen);
}
```

```html
<section class="section-introduction">
  <h2 class="section-heading">Color pallete</h2>
  <div class="container">
      <div class="brightgreen-circle circle ">
        <p>brightgreen</p><span>#F4FF96</span>
      </div>
      <div class="yellowgreen-circle circle">
        <p>yellowgreen</p><span>#ECF22E</span>
      </div>
      <div class="left-semi-circle semi-circle">
        <p>White</p><span>#FFFFFF</span>
      </div>
      <div class="right-semi-circle semi-circle">
        <p>Black</p><span>#000000</span></p>
      </div>
      <div class="applegreen-circle circle">
        <p>applegreen</p><span>#BCDD15</span>
      </div>
      <div class="brightgreen-circle2 circle">
        <p>brightgreen</p><span>#F4FF96</span>
      </div>
</section>
```

note the demo sets font-size with `font-size: clamp(10px, 1.5vw, 30px);` so you can see it rescale if open the snippet in fullpage.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The gradient looks like a simple solution. But when I'm using it in a single container, all circles stop to be responsive.
They don't move with the box and overflow it when the screen is smaller.  Again I don't know, where is the problem.